# How can I calculate the letterbox size with this class?

Tags: java, opengl, libgdx

I have the following Java class I've written for a LibGdx OpenGL project.
The camera keeps the aspect ratio of the screen no matter how you resize it by letterboxing either the top and bottom, or the sides. So far, so good.

The issue comes when I try to obtain the mouse x, y coordinates of a click, and the letterbox is involved for that axis. 
First here is the class:

```
public class Camera {

private static float viewportWidth;
private static float viewportHeight;
private static float aspectRatio;
private static float barSize;

/**
  * Creates an orthographic camera where the "play area" has the given viewport size. The viewport will be scaled to maintain the aspect ratio.
  * 
  * @param virtualWidth the width of the game screen in virtual pixels.
  * @param virtualHeight the height of the game screen in virtual pixels.
  * @return the new camera.
  * 
  */

public static OrthographicCamera createCamera(float virtualWidth, float virtualHeight) {

    aspectRatio = virtualWidth / virtualHeight;


    float physicalWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    float physicalHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();

    if (physicalWidth / physicalHeight >= aspectRatio) {
//      Letterbox left and right.
         viewportHeight = virtualHeight;
         viewportWidth = viewportHeight * physicalWidth / physicalHeight;
         barSize = ????;
    }
    else {
//      Letterbox above and below.
       viewportWidth = virtualWidth;
       viewportHeight = viewportWidth * physicalHeight / physicalWidth;
       barSize = ????;
    }

    OrthographicCamera cam = new OrthographicCamera(viewportWidth , viewportHeight);
    cam.position.set(virtualWidth / 2, virtualHeight / 2, 0);
    cam.rotate(180, 1, 0, 0);
    cam.update();
    Gdx.app.log("BTLog", "barSize:"+barSize);
    return cam;
}

public static float getViewportWidth() {
    return viewportWidth;
}

public static float getViewportHeight() {
    return viewportHeight;
}
}
```

LibGdx supplies me the x and y coordinates when an even happens, and I need to translate these raw coordinates into the scale of my camera (the virtual height and width).

When the screen is stretched (no letterboxing at all), it's pretty easy to obtain the x and y coordinates by using:

```
xRelative = (int) (x / (float)Gdx.graphics.getWidth() * Camera.getViewportWidth());
yRelative = (int) (y / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * Camera.getViewportHeight());
```

The problem is when the letterboxes come into play, it throws off the coordinate for that axis. I know I need to take into account the width of the letterboxing, but i'm having a hell of a time figuring how to calculate it.

Above where I have "barSize = ????;" my first instinct was to do this:
    barSize = physicalHeight - viewportHeight; // to use height for example

Once I get the barSize, i'm fairly sure I can use this to get the right numbers (using the y axis for example):

```
yRelative = (int) (y / (float)Gdx.graphics.getHeight() * Camera.getViewportHeight() - Camera.getBarSize());
```

But the numbers don't match up. Any suggestions would be a really appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ray ray = camera.getPickRay(x, y);
System.out.println(ray.origin.x);
System.out.println(ray.origin.y);
```